# Facebook SDK 4.0 - FacebookSession - Session will not validate

Tags: php, facebook, session, sdk

I’m building a FB tab page.
On the main page, I can successfully set up a FacebookSession using the signed_request.
I start a session and store `$facebookSession->getToken()` in `$_SESSION['token']`.

```
$session = FacebookSession::newSessionFromSignedRequest($signedRequest);
$_SESSION['token'] = $session->getToken();
```

When I navigate to another PHP page in the IFrame, I create another FacebookSession, based on the stored token.

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appId, $appSecret);
$session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']);
```

The session is created, but when I try to validate this session, the SDK throws a “Session has expired, or is not valid for this app”-exception.

```
$session->validate()
```

Any ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: If you debug the token in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ what does it say?

Comment: It's not going to say much, I'm currently working on a local server where my app in development is pointing to (https://local.dev)

Comment: The debug tool also debugs tokens, it's not just for URLs - are you sure you're using the same app ID for the page tab app as you are in your PHP code?

Comment: Yes, all app data matches, if it were that simple. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi think I found the answer.

The FacebookSession-class has 1 mandatory constructor argument $accessToken and one optional $parsedSignedRequest.

I was only storing the token in the session and using only this one.
I'm currently also storing the parsed Signed Request in the session (`$session->getSignedRequestData()`) and passing it along with the token as constructor variables.
This will resume the session.

Storing on the main page:

```
$_SESSION['token'] = $this->fbSession->getToken();
$_SESSION['signed_data'] = $this->fbSession->getSignedRequestData();
```

Reinitialisation of the session on the second page:

```
$token = $_SESSION["token"];
$parsedSignedData = $_SESSION["parsedSignedData"];
$session = new FacebookSession($token, $parsedSignedData);
```

I have no clue if this is the right way to do it, but at least it works. :)

Feel free to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do would be just use `$token` to create the new session

On the first page it should be

```
$_SESSION['token'] = $this->fbSession->getToken();
```

On the second page it should be

```
$token = $_SESSION["token"];
$session = new FacebookSession($token);
```

This will work as `SignedRequest` should be `NULL` by default.